# Finding Next Ascii Space With _mm_cmpeq_epi8 Returning 0

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

I have this string being passed into my parse route method.

```
  route_start = 4;
  parse_route_simd("GET /0000_0000_/ HTTP/1.1\r\n", 27);
  assert(route_end == 15);
```

```
const char spaces[17] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = "                \0";

 void parse_route_simd(const char *buffer, const int buffer_len) {
  int index_simd;
  int curr_index = route_start;
  register __m128i xmm0, xmm1, xmm2;
  register unsigned int eax;
  register unsigned char ebx;
  while (buffer_len - curr_index >= 16) {
    debug_print("route_start %d\nindex_simd %d\nbuff %s\nspaces :%s:\n",
                route_start, index_simd, buffer + curr_index, spaces);
    xmm0 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)buffer + curr_index);
    xmm1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)spaces);
    xmm2 = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(xmm0, xmm1);
    eax = _mm_movemask_epi8(xmm2);
    debug_print("eax %d\n", eax);
    index_simd = __builtin_ffsll(eax);
```

I am losing my mind, because I can't figure out why eax in this code is returning 0;

Comment: Style tip: don't use asm register names as C variable names.  Use meaningful var names like `__m128i spaces = _mm_set1_epi8(' ');` or `int cmpmask = _mm_movemask_epi8(cmpv)`.  Speaking of spaces, your [mcve] doesn't define `spaces`.  Use a debugger to look at your vectors.

Comment: @PeterCordes updated. forgot to copy that.

Comment: Ok, so your spaces is just a clunky inconvenient way to write `spaces = _mm_set1_epi8(' ')`.  IDK, should work as long as the spaces are farther than 16 bytes from the end of the buffer.  Single-step with a debugger and see what's going on.  This still isn't a [mcve].  (Do note that `ffs` is 1-indexed, so it will return 1 if the low bit is set, i.e. the match is at `buffer + curr_index + 0`).  Also weird that you're reading a global variable after calling the function, instead of making it return an `int` or `size_t` or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(const __m128i *)buffer + curr_index` is a problem.
You need `(const __m128i *)(buffer + curr_index)` to do `char*` address math, *then* cast to `__m128i*`.

casts have higher operator precedence than `+`.

Another common technique to avoid this mistake is `(__m128i*) &buffer[curr_index]`

A debugger should show that with `curr_index = 1`, you're loading from 16 bytes into the array, going forward by one `__m128i`, because that's the pointer type involved in the addition.